# AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22

Tags: android

Help me please, how fix this?

```
public class VisualizerCapture extends Activity implements Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener
private Visualizer mVisualizer;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
    setupVisualizer();

private void setupVisualizer() {
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(8);      //test
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(this,250,false,true);        
            Log.v("ABS","setupVisualizer" + mVisualizer.getEnabled());    //log
```

This code throws error:
ERROR/AudioEffect(2393): set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22

that was in xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>             
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

logcat:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{blabla}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -4
        at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.(Visualizer.java:182)
        at com.blablabeta.gui.VisualizerCapture.onCreate(EqVisualizerCaptureAudio.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

That is it?
and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was gone then I test my app on real phone.
somthing wrong with emulator.

Answer (score 5):

When using the `Visualizer` on session 0 you need to have `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` and `RECORD_AUDIO` permissions, but I'm guessing that your app has those because otherwise you'd get a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error (`-1` if I remember correctly).

Status -22 ought to be `BAD_VALUE`. It's not entirely clear to me from the information available in the question why this would happen. Perhaps there's more information available in the logcat output in addition to that line you pasted. Potential reasons for why you'd end up with a `BAD_VALUE` status would be e.g. that the effect isn't found, or that the effect already has been inserted in the effect chain.

Comment: added logcat, its a bit fixed, but only in file names.

Comment: @Michael: Same error i found on the constructer of the Equalizer. Please help for that.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to request permissions from the user if am not mistaken? I had the same problem adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Is only part of what is required. Have a look on here: [Unable to request RECORD_AUDIO permission in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304399/unable-to-request-record-audio-permission-in-android)

Gives pretty much everything you need.