# Unable to request RECORD_AUDIO permission in Android

Tags: android, permissions, audio-recording

I am developing an Android application that has its own video recorder feature. For that I need to request RECORD_AUDIO permission from the user. But when I request the permission, it is not showing the prompt to get the permission from the user.

This is my function that checks if the app needs to request permission and it does automatically if required.

```
private boolean isRecordAudioPermissionGranted()
   {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // put your code for Version>=Marshmallow
            return true;
         } else {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
               Toast.makeText(this,
                  "App required access to audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
            },AUDIO_RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
            return false;
         }

      } else {
         // put your code for Version < Marshmallow
         return true;
      }
   }
```

In the onCreate of the Activity, I call the function like this.

```
if(!isRecordAudioPermissionGranted())
      {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Need to request permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
else{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No need to request permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The app is saying that it needs to request permission, but it is just not prompting the request permission dialog. What is wrong with my code?

This are the permissions I added and use in the manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"/>

   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="true"/>
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance" android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For [RECORD_AUDIO permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECORD_AUDIO), correct permission string is

```
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

In your manifest you are using

`<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>`

which in incorrect and it must be

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>`

Answer (score 5):

add this in manifest file

in java 
  //Requesting run-time permissions

```
//Create placeholder for user's consent to record_audio permission.
//This will be used in handling callback
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;

private void requestAudioPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant permissions to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Give user option to still opt-in the permissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

        } else {
            // Show user dialog to grant permission to record audio
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
    }
    //If permission is granted, then go ahead recording audio
    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //Go ahead with recording audio now
        recordAudio();
    }
}

//Handling callback
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay!
                recordAudio();
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions Denied to record audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ALSO ADD THIS IN MANIFEST <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />